# exclude certain characters while matching a regex

Tags: ruby, regex

```
/[a-zA-Z]*/
```

The above matches all characters from a-z, but I would like to exclude when there is 'if' in the string.

Tried `[^if]` but couldn't accomplish what I was hoping for.

**[EDIT]** I have a formula evaluator which returns some value:

```
value = "if(a < b,a,b+1)"
formula = value.gsub(/[a-zA-Z]*/,'1')
verify = Calc.evaluate(formula)
```

I am trying to assign `1` to `a` and `b` inside the string and check if the formula is valid and evaluated.

```
Expected Output: "if(1 < 1,1,1+1)"
```

Comment: Are you trying to parse a programming language this way?

Comment: [] is a character class ^negates whats in the class [^if] would match anything that is not an 'i' or an 'f'

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Actually I am not trying to match, i am trying to replace char using gsub for a formula which looks like this "if(a < b,a,b)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get want you want you can use `gsub` like this:

```
"if(a < b,a,b+1)".gsub(/[a-zA-Z]+/){|m| m == 'if' ? m : '1' }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
/((?!if )[a-zA-Z])*/

string = "abc"
string.match(/((?!if )[a-zA-Z])*/) 
# MatchData "abc"
string = "if abc" 
# MatchData ""
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But please check my latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to assign 1 to a and b inside the string...

Well, if you're trying to do that, then why are you messing with anything but `a` or `b`?

```
str = 'if(a < b,a,b+1)'
str.gsub(/\b[ab]\b/, '1') # => "if(1 < 1,1,1+1)"
```

`\b` is a word-boundary marker, so `\b[ab]\b` means `a` or `b` has to be an individual character.